# Get Thread ID of the initiator of a Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, command, task-parallel-library, deadlock

I've a queue of commands. One thread is trying to execute those commands.

Other threads can ask to pause the execution(and they will be blocked until the current command execution is done), and resume them.

When the thread wants to execute thoses commands(at regular interval) it flags that it want to execute commands(and is blocked until all "pause" are removed.

The only issue is that some of thoses commands might try to pause the command execution(because of some event that listen some other event, ...).

The way it has been handled until now is to store the ThreadId of the thread executing the commands, and ignore the pause request if it comes from this thread.
(You don't have to tell me it's a shity design, I know, but I've to do with it :( ).

One class is containing all this `CommandQueue` logic:

```
public void PauseDataCommandProcessing()
{
    if (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == m_processDataCommandThreadId)
    {
        return;
    }
    lock (m_pauseLock)
    {
        m_pauseCounter++;
        if (m_dataCommandInProgress)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(m_pauseLock);
        }
    }
}


public void ResumeDataCommandProcessing()
{
    if (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == m_processDataCommandThreadId)
    {
        return;
    }
    lock (m_pauseLock)
    {
        m_pauseCounter--;
        if (m_pauseCounter == 0)
        {
            Monitor.PulseAll(m_pauseLock);
        }
    }
}

//Thoses methods are called by the command executers
public void FlagCommandsExecutionInProgress()
{
    m_processDataCommandThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    lock (m_pauseLock)
    {
        while (m_pauseCounter > 0)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(m_pauseLock);
        }
        m_dataCommandInProgress = true;
    }
}

public void FlagCommandsExecutionFinished()
{
    lock (m_pauseLock)
    {
        m_dataCommandInProgress = false;
        Monitor.PulseAll(m_pauseLock);
    }
}
```

Here is how I execute them basically

```
CommandContainer.FlagCommandsExecutionInProgress();
try{
    IEnumerable<CommandInfo> commandSet =CommandContainer.RetrieveCommands();//Get the current commands list
    foreach (CommandInfo command in commandSet){
        command.Execute();
    }
}finally{
    CommandContainer.FlagCommandsExecutionFinished();
}
```

In order to increase the speed of execution of thoses commands I wanted to regroup the command by "Target"(each command is applied to a specific object), and then execute in parallel each group of commands.

The idea was to execute them like this:

```
CommandContainer.FlagCommandsExecutionInProgress();
try{
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, CommandInfo>>  groupedCommandSet =CommandContainer.RetrieveCommands().GroupBy(c=>c.Target);//Get the current commands list
    Parallel.ForEach(groupedCommandSet,commandSet=>{
        foreach (CommandInfo command in commandSet){
            command.Execute();
        }
    } );
}finally{
    CommandContainer.FlagCommandsExecutionFinished();
}
```

But unfortunately, they will have a different ThreadId and I get some deadlocks, because they wait on themselfs to finish.

Assuming that I cannot change the way those pause are asked, do you see any way to solve my issue?

Comment: What exactly can you not change? Just the interface, or also the bodies of the `PauseDataCommandProcessing()` and `ResumeDataCommandProcessing()` methods?

Comment: @svick The Pause & Resume, but I think I found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended by doing this: I don't know if there is a better solution, but it seems to work:

```
private HashSet<int> m_processDataCommandThreadIds = new HashSet<int>();

public void PauseDataCommandProcessing()
{
    if (m_processDataCommandThreadIds.Contains(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
    {
        return;
    }
    lock (m_pauseLock)
    {
        m_pauseCounter++;
        if (m_dataCommandInProgress)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(m_pauseLock);
        }
    }
}


public void ResumeDataCommandProcessing()
{
    if (m_processDataCommandThreadIds.Contains(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
    {
        return;
    }
    lock (m_pauseLock)
    {
        m_pauseCounter--;
        if (m_pauseCounter == 0)
        {
            Monitor.PulseAll(m_pauseLock);
        }
    }
}

//Thoses methods are called by the command executers
public void FlagCommandsExecutionInProgress()
{
    m_processDataCommandThreadIds.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    lock (m_pauseLock)
    {
        while (m_pauseCounter > 0)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(m_pauseLock);
        }
        m_dataCommandInProgress = true;
    }
}

public void FlagCommandsExecutionFinished()
{
    m_processDataCommandThreadIds.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    lock (m_pauseLock)
    {
        m_dataCommandInProgress = false;
        Monitor.PulseAll(m_pauseLock);
    }
}
```